# Getting response 444 when making request to a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to make a request to a webpage using the code below and i am getting response 444.
Is there anything i can to about it?

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.pseudosite.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response) # <Response [444]>
```

[*http.dev* website](https://http.dev/444) says the following:

> When the 444 No Response status code is generated, the server returns
> no information to the client and closes the HTTP Connection. This
> error message can be found in the nginx logs and will not be sent to
> the client. It is useful for dealing with malicious HTTP requests,
> such as one that includes an illegal Host header.

I am trying to webscrape that website using python, but I am blocked at first step.

Comment: post the real webpage that you want to crawl.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you need to add headers to view this webpage. If you open devtools on your browser, then you should see a 'get' request; if you now click on the 'Headers' tab, you can create a dictionary with the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).